# Central store for build artifacts in .Net

Tags: msbuild, bamboo

I know Maven has a central repository that you can upload build artifacts (assemblies) and reference them in your build script so that you get the latest versions.

Is there any similar tool (other than Maven for .Net) that provides a way to centrally store artifacts and reference them in MSBuild scripts?

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate a library solution we have that is used across all our other solutions (contains common data access, schemas, etc.)

We don't always automatically want it included in our projects as sometimes we need to stay on a particular version for one project until that project is ready to upgrade to the latest.

Comment: not exactly supported, automated, or easy to do, but you can create a "local" nuget repository to store artifacts like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd create a build system that allows publishing packaged 'modules' from one end, and importing from the other end.

You create a shared directory at a global place within your organization and this becomes your "central Repository" you're talking of.

Alas, I'm not aware of any public implementation of such an msbuild system.